# Finding the angles of a rhombus when only the diagonal vectors are given.

Tags: vectors

The question had given the vectors representing the diagonals of the rhombus. The vectors are $\overrightarrow{A} = 3\hat{i}-4\hat{j}-\hat{k}$ and $\overrightarrow{B} = 2\hat{i}+3\hat{j}-6\hat{k}$.
How am I supposed to find the angles?
My initial approach to the problem was like the following -
I defined the rhombus as $PQRS$ so that the vectors $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ and $\overrightarrow{QR}$ add up to give $\overrightarrow{A}$ by the parallelogram law of vector addition and their difference will give me the $\overrightarrow{B}$. As the other two vectors are just parallel to the $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ and $\overrightarrow{QR}$ and since parallel translation does not change the vector I kept the vectors same as their respective parallel vectors.Now if we find $\overrightarrow{PQ}\cdot\overrightarrow{QR}$ then from that point I can find the angle between that two vectors. But it turns out that the angle is an obtuse angle instead of an acute angle and in addition to that all the angles are turning out to be the same as all the parallel vectors are assumed same which is a complete disaster.
Can anyone help me with this problem?
I found this problem in Schaum's Vector Analysis written by Murray R Spiegel in the second chapter, where I also found the answer to the question. It shows only two answers for the angles. They are, $arccos{\frac{23}{75}}$ and $180^{\circ}-arccos{\frac{23}{75}}$.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

HINT… by drawing a simple diagram you should be able to see that you just need to calculate the vectors $A+B$ and $A-B$ and find the angle between these and you will get the answer.